# POST submission in AMP HTML/PHP form with URL redirect

Tags: php, forms, post, amp-html

I have a simple HTML/PHP form (say https://example.com/dir/BOO.php) with 3 fields which I am developing for being AMP-compatible and should use POST method:

```
<form method="post" action-xhr="https://example.com/dir/BOO.php" target="_top">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." value="Input Name" required>
  <span>Code:</span><select name="code" required><option value="" disabled selected>Choose Code</option><option value='YOYO'>YOYO</option><br><option value='BOO'>BOO</option><br><option value='HELLO'>HELLO</option></select>
  <span>Date:</span><select name="dt"><option value='2019-11-29'>Fri, 29Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-27'>Wed, 27Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-26'>Tue, 26Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-25'>Mon, 25Nov19</option><br><option value='2019-11-22'>Fri, 22Nov19</option><br></select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

In the same BOO.php, I have the following PHP code at the top of the page to process the values:

```
echo "Printing new form values:<br>";
if(!empty($_POST)){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: Content-Type");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ". str_replace('.', '-','https://example.com') .".cdn.ampproject.org");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: https://www.example.com");
    header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: https://www.example.com");
    header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
    header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    header("AMP-Redirect-To: https://example.com/dir/YOYO.php");

}

echo '{ "POST": "' . print_r($_POST, true) . '"}';
echo "FINISHED-Printing new form values:<br>";
?>
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

1) Both BOO.php and YOYO.php have identical HTML and PHP code as above - they should be an AMP-compatible page which I believe has been taken care of in the above code.

2) When I visit the (https://example.com/dir/BOO.php) page in a browser, it should have the default values as set in the HTML form. However, when I select/input other values - like insert my name in the name field, select the code "YOYO" from drop-down, and select date as "Wed, 27Nov19", and hit the "Submit" button, it should take me to the (https://example.com/dir/YOYO.php) page, and

3) All the selected/inserted values should be captured in the YOYO page (which is what I am trying to print through - `echo '{ "POST": "' . print_r($_POST, true) . '"}';` - code.

The problem is that even after selecting/inserting the values on the first BOO.php page and hitting the submit button, the page is not moving at all.

BOO and YOYO php pages have the same code for processing this form values.

Any idea on where am I going wrong?

And to add: I also have the necessary script async for AMP-FORM in the  tag:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
plus....<style amp-boilerplate>, etc...
```

Thanks